# Check if nested JSON structure contains key

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a deeply nested JSON object, with several unknown arrays and properties contains a property that I'm looking for. I'm looking for a property that is called "isInvalid". If the field is there and the value of that key is true. I want to return false.

```
var checkValidity = function (data) {
    for (var property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (property == "isInvalid" && data[property] === true) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (typeof data[property] === "object" && data[property] !== null) {
                    this.checkValidity(data[property]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the code I've been trying out but I'm unable to get that to work. I have been looking into underscore also, but cant find the needed functions. Anyone has an idea? (No reg exp please)

Comment: @peter you can use Object.keys then check if the isInvalid is existing in the array of keys

Comment: `this.checkValidity` is invalid, `checkValidity` is a variable, not a property of an object unless you are attaching it to some object and not showing it

Comment: please use a named function for recursion.

Comment: Is `isInvalid` key of the input object or you want to apply logic over there to test valid object ?

Comment: I just wan't to check if the object, and the nested properties actually contains that key, and check if the value is true. I don't wan't any more logic what so ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just want to check for property presence regardless of its particular location within JSON, then the easiest/fastest way is substring search in the **source JSON string**. If the latter is well-formed, then the property should be encoded in JSON as `'"isInvalid":true'`.

```
var checkValidity = function (jsonstr) {
    return jsonstr.indexOf('"isInvalid":true') >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, really like this solution. No recursive methods needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this

```
var s = {a:'1',b:'2'};

if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(s).indexOf('a') != -1){
console.log('available');
}else{
  console.log('Not available');
};
```

editing answer... **UPDATE**

```
var s = {
  a1: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: {
    a: '11'
  }
};
var checkValidity = function (data) {
  if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).indexOf('a') != - 1) {
    console.log('Found that key!!!');
  } else {
    for (var property in data) {

      if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(property).indexOf('a') != - 1) {
         console.log('Found that key!!!');

      } else {
        if (typeof data[property] === 'object' && data[property] !== null) {
          console.log('not found continue in inner obj..');
          this.checkValidity(data[property]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
checkValidity(s);
```

Comment: Please read the question. This only checks one level of the JSON.

Comment: @petur I was editing the answer! I just post an idea to test that. You can check with update.

Answer (score 1):

It tests for every nesting level the property `isInvalid` and if not, all other properties as object and their content. [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) breaks if one return is `false`.

```js
function checkValidity(data) {
    return !data.isInvalid && Object.keys(data).every(function (property) {
        if (typeof data[property] === "object" && data[property] !== null) {
            return checkValidity(data[property]);
        }
        return true;
    });
}

var data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        isInvalid: true,
        a: false
    }
};

document.write('checkValidity() should be false: ' + checkValidity(data) + '<br>');
data.c.isInvalid = false;
document.write('checkValidity() should be true: ' + checkValidity(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

For complex json searching like this, I would use jsonpath ( http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ ) which is the JSON equivalent of xpath.

To find the isInvalid field no matter where it is in the json, you would use it like this:

```
 jsonPath(data, "$..isInvalid")
```